# Unable to understand lambdas expression in angular2?

Tags: angular

**Angular 2 code**

```
 heroes => this.heroes = heroes;
```

please tell me what this line exactly mean to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
heroes => this.heroes = heroes;
```

Is a function that takes a parameter `heroes` and the body of the function is

```
this.heroes = heroes
```

which assigns the parameter to `this.heroes`.

The arrow function has an implicit return which means that the return value is the result of the body.

```
this.heroes = heroes
```

returns `heroes`

The main difference is that `=>` instead of

```
function(heroes) { this.heroes = heroes; }
```

ensures that `this.` keeps pointing to the current class instance similar to

```
(function(heroes) { this.heroes = heroes; }).bind(this)
```

Comment: `getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe((function(heroes) { this.heroes = heroes;console.log(this.heroes);
 }), error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    console.log(this.heroes);
      }`

In this code first console is printing heroes object but second console is not printing. Why? @Gunter

Comment: As mentioned `this.` is not retained with `function(heroes)` instead of `heroes => ...`. With `function` `this.` points to the enclosing function.

Comment: You forgot to mention the lambda also returns a value.

Comment: @AviadP. you are right of course. That's an important aspect.

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, we call this an *Arrow Function*, which is a shorthand version of a function declaration, and at the same time, binds the `this` inside the function.

Its form in ES5 syntax would be:

```
...
var self = this;

function someFunction(heroes) {

  self.heroes = heroes;
}
...
```

I don't have the rest of your code, so I only assumed some parts.

Basically, when we use `this` inside a function, `this` refers to *only the scope inside the function*. It overrides the `this` of the function's outer scope. We will have to create a reference to the outer `this`, (such as `self`) in order for the function to have access to it.

Read more here: [MDN: Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

Your method send 'heroes' data then you put then into your variable this.heroes (two differents things)

Comment: heroes temporary exist, this.heroes is a parameter of your class (generaly)

Comment: but when I mention the same thing shown as below, It's not working\n
`function(heros){
 this.heroes = heroes;
return this.heroes;
}
`